# Получить данные из папки

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть папка которая содержит ещё папки и файлы! Как получить данные из всех файлов находящихся в главной папке?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Очевидно,

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath))
{
    // получаете данные из файла по пути filePath
}
```

Это обходит только файлы, содержащиеся непосредственно в *главной* папке.

Если вам нужно обойти рекурсивно файлы во *всех* подкаталогах, вместо `Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath)` применяйте `Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

---

Как правильно подсказывает @iluxa1810 в комментариях, для случая, когда вам нужна особая политика по поводу исключений (например, игнорировать их, или повторно запросить данные, или спросить пользователя), нужен намного более сложный код, с рекурсивными вызовами функций.

Что-то подобное должно работать:

```
static void ProcessDirectory(string path)
{
    IEnumerable<string> filePaths = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    try
    {
        filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) // каталог внезапно исчез?
    {
        // реакция?
    }
    catch (IOException) // каталог внезапно подменили файлом? или сбойный диск?
    {
        // реакция?
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) // нет прав на каталог, что делаем?
    {
        // реакция?
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException) // нет прав на каталог, что делаем?
    {
        // реакция?
    }

    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        try
        {
            // получаете данные из файла по пути filePath
        }
        catch (тут нужно поймать исключения, которые могут
               случиться при обработке одного файла)
        {
            // реакция?
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<string> subdirPaths = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    try
    {
        subdirPaths = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
    }
    // те же исключения, те же проблемы
    // ...

    foreach (string subdirPath in subdirPaths)
        ProcessDirectory(subdirPath); // рекурсивный вызов
}
```

Comment: Надо бы упомянуть про исключение при обходе вложенных каталогов, если наткнуться на директории без нужных прав=> все может обвалится на пол пути...=> вложенные директории лучше обходить ручками.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это да, но в принципе непонятно, что делать в случае отсутствия прав. Спокойно проглотить и пропустить? Бросить исключение? Попытаться ещё раз? Тут всё сложно. Например, если вам нужно удалить каталог, и вы хотите перед этим удалить все файлы, то стратегия «поймать исключение и проигнорировать» может и не сработать. Но в целом да, для разных задач нужны разные стратегии.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Добавил код.

Comment: Ну дубликат же?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Наверняка. Но если кто-нибудь найдёт канонический вопрос, я проголосую тоже.