# Ошибка попытки доступа к каталогу C#

Tags: c#

Задача:
Нужно пройтись по всем папкам Windows (можно пропустить системные) и найти определенный файл (это я сделал) Вот:

```
string[] allFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles($@"C:\", $"erni.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string filename = textBox1.Text;

foreach (string file in allFoundFiles)
{
    Process.Start(file);
}
```

Проблема вот в чем, когда он доходит до системных папок, он выдает исключение:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Documents and Settings"."

В try:catch пробовал, нифига не понял.
В других темах тоже толком не понятно ничерта, не мог бы кто нибудь помочь? Либо сделать доступ, либо пропускать все системные папки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628606/220553

Comment: Задача в том, что он ищет файл по всем каталогам, а не по отдельному пути

Comment: И что? В тех или иных вариациях этот вопрос уже несколько раз задавался на ru so, не раз отвечали. Имху, тут надо не стесняться, а дубликатить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
foreach (string file in allFoundFiles)
{
 try {
     Process.Start(file);
 }
 catch {
  continue;
 }
}
```

Comment: Думаю, нужно обернуть весь цикл в try:catch и поставить continue, просто то, что вы обернули выполнял функцию запуска при успешном исходе

Comment: continue в не цикла?

Comment: Это не ответ. Данный код никак не решает проблему.

Comment: На самом деле это ответ на пропускать не доступные файлы

Comment: Нет. Исключение выбрасывается при вызове метода `Directory.GetFiles`. То есть до вашего кода дело не дойдёт.

Comment: Я уже понял и исправил проблему. Использовал метод пропуска системных файлов.