# Все файлы из папки и подпапок C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Использую данный код, но он выдаёт список из нескольких подпапок.
А надо все файлы из всех папок + путь основного каталога и вложенных.

```
        DirectoryInfo diFromDir = new DirectoryInfo(@PathClient);

        DirectoryInfo[] diFromArr = diFromDir.GetDirectories();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo DirName in diFromArr)
        {
            DirectoryInfo fFromDir = new DirectoryInfo(@PathClient + "/" + DirName);

            foreach (FileInfo Fname in DirName.GetFiles())
            {
                FileInfo ufInfo = new FileInfo(@PathClient + @"\" + DirName + @"\" + Fname);
                AllFilesSize = AllFilesSize + ufInfo.Length;

                listBox.Items.Add(DirName + "\\" + Fname);
                AllFilesCnt++;
                Properties.Settings.Default.AllFilesCnt = AllFilesCnt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @kotleni - а зачем она здесь ?

Comment: Если вам нужны лишь файлы, которые находятся в директории (включая внутренние), то можете взять просто `var files = Directory.GetFiles("path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`, но учтите, возьмет все, включая системные (к которым у вас нету даже доступа). Если нужна своя логика, то выше вам сказали - рекурсия, то есть метод, который получает все файлы в директории, а если находит директорию, то запускает сам себя, чтоб получить файлы и так до тех пор, пока не пройдете все директории, их помещаете в список, который дальше и обрабатываете как вам надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - а можете помочь исправить код чтобы он работал с рекурскией?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628606/220553