# Проблема с удалением файлов

Tags: c#

```
int i = 0;
        string[] AllFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(fn => Path.GetFileName(fn)).ToArray();
        string[] AllFoundFiles2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        private void fff()
        {
            int iteration = AllFoundFiles.Length;
            Label[] label1 = new Label[iteration];
            Button[] button = new Button[iteration];
            ;
            for (; i < iteration; i++)
            {
                label1[i] = new Label();

                label1[i].Location = new Point(120, 60 + i * 31);

                label1[i].Width = 300;
                label1[i].Text = AllFoundFiles[i];
                label1[i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15);
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label1[i]);
                label1[i].BringToFront();
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label1[i]);
                label1[i].BringToFront();
                button[i] = new Button();
                button[i].BringToFront();

                button[i].Location = new Point(450, 60 + i * 31);
                button[i].Text = "Удалить";
                button[i].Name = AllFoundFiles2[i];
                button[i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
                button[i].Click += ButtonOnClick;
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(button[i]);
                button[i].BringToFront();
                panel2.BringToFront();

            }



        }
        public void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            DialogResult Messagedelete = MessageBox.Show(
                "Вы точно хотите удалить этот файл?Вернуть его будет не возможно",
                       "Information",
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                       MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1
                );
            if (Messagedelete == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                var button = (Button)sender;
                File.Delete(button.Name);
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Remove(button);
                for (int i = 0; i < AllFoundFiles.Length; i++)
                {
                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.Location = new Point(450, 60 + i * 31);
                    label.Text = "Удалён";
                    label.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15);
                    tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label);
                }

            }
        }
```

Всем добрый день, я делаю поиск всех файлов на диске С, и мне выдает ошибку `UnauthorizedAccessException`, но решить через пустой catch нельзя так как массив где хранится все файлы используется в двух методах, вынести `try catch` тоже нельзя, как быть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628606/220553

Comment: Что значит "нельзя"? И что с того что массив ещё где-то используется!? Просто заводите try/cath там где конкретно вам нужно на конкретные действия, которые вы хотите произвести. Используйте списки вместо массивов, если вы хотите удалить то, что можно удалить и получить список оставшихся файлов. Заводите try/cath вокруг File.Delete(button.Name); и остального...

Answer (score 0):

Сделаю ревью вашего кода.

Что это за название: `fff`? Что делает этот метод? Фыфыкает?
Он создаёт контролы, предназначенные для удаления файлов. Поэтому можно назвать метод, например, `CreateDeleteControls`.

---

Вы дважды обращаетесь к файловой системе: `Directory.GetFiles` получая одни и те же файлы. А это весьма накладная операция, если файлов окажется много.
Можно поступить так (и сделать эти массивы локальными):

```
string[] FoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string[] FoundNameFiles = FoundFiles.Select(fn => Path.GetFileName(fn)).ToArray();
```

Но от второго массива можно вообще избавиться. Ниже я покажу, как.

---

Почему `i` является полем формы? Это должна быть локальная переменная.

---

Некоторые куски кода вы вызываете дважды. Например:

```
button[i].BringToFront();
```

Будьте внимательнее, удаляйте такие повторы.

---

Ещё пара слов о нейминге.

Обработчик нажатия кнопок я бы назвал `DeleteButton_Click`. Это стандартный шаблон именования.

Названия массивов у вас:

```
Label[] label1
Button[] button
```

Ну что это такое? Названия коллекций должны быть во множественном числе: `buttons`, `labels`.
А самое главное - они вообще не нужны. Создаваемые контролы помещаются в коллекцию `Controls`. Массивы можно убрать.

---

Создание шрифтов - довольно тяжёлая операция. Поэтому лучше сделать шрифты полями формы и далее назначать их.

---

---

Теперь посмотрим на код в обработчике события.

В заголовке MessageBox'а обычно показывают название приложения.

Иконка должна быть либо `MessageBoxIcon.Warning` (предупреждение) - ведь удаление файла потенциально опасно, либо `MessageBoxIcon.Question` - вы же вопрос задаёте: "Удалить?"

---

В цикле добавляются лейблы "Удалён" для всех файлов. Просто их не видно под кнопками. Не стоит так делать. Это и затраты ресурсов, и будет совершенно непонятно, зачем так сделано, тому, кто будет поддерживать этот код в будущем.

---

Индекс `i` можно было бы передавать в свойстве `Tag` кнопки. Примерно так же, как вы передаёте название файла в свойстве `Name`.
При создании кнопки: `button.Tag = i;`
Его получение в событии: `int i = (int)button.Tag;`.

Но можно поступить ещё проще. Лейбл с надписью "Удалён" помещается в те же координаты, где была кнопка. Вот координаты кнопки и возьмём.

---

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
private readonly Font bigFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15);
private readonly Font smallFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);

private void CreateDeleteControls()
{
    try
    {
        string[] filesToDelete = Directory.GetFiles(
            @"C:\Users\", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        for (int i = 0; i < filesToDelete.Length; i++)
        {
            var label = new Label
            {
                Location = new Point(120, 60 + i * 31),
                Width = 300,
                Text = Path.GetFileName(filesToDelete[i]),
                Font = bigFont
            };
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label);

            var button = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(450, 60 + i * 31),
                Text = "Удалить",
                Name = filesToDelete[i],
                Font = smallFont
            };
            button.Click += DeleteButton_Click;
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Название приложения",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
public void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
        "Вы точно хотите удалить этот файл? Вернуть его будет не возможно",
        "Название приложения",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1
    );

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        try
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            File.Delete(button.Name);
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Remove(button);

            var label = new Label
            {
                Location = button.Location,
                Text = "Удалён",
                Font = bigFont
            };
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Название приложения",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Учтите, что все обращения к файловой системе: `Directory.GetFiles`, `File.Delete` - могут привести к исключениям. Поэтому их обязательно следует обернуть в `try-catch`.

---

Названия файлов в разных папках могут совпадать. Вы же получаете файлы с опцией `SearchOption.AllDirectories` - в текущем каталоге и подкаталогах. А выводите вы только имя файла без пути. В итоге пользователь не будет знать, из какой папки он удаляет файл. Я бы показывал полный путь.

---

Кроме того, вместо ручного задания координат: `120, 60 + i * 31` я бы применил, например, `TableLayoutPanel`. Он автоматически расставит контролы по строкам и колонкам.