# Поиск по всем вложенным каталогам

Tags: c#

У меня есть код который выводит все каталоги из указанного места

```
var dirinfo = new Directoryinfo("\\test\\exapmle");
dir = dirinfo .GetDirectories();
```

Но я хочу вывести все подпапки включая все вложенные в эти подпапки(то есть полностью пройтись вглубь папок и ввести все папки которые возможно вывести)
Я смотрел в интернете куча примеров но они только выводит подпапки 1 уровня а дальше не заходят как можно реализовать данный алгоритм чтобы он еще быстро работал?
а что касается

**SearchOption.AllDirectories**

он не работает так как есть некоторые папки где нет доступа

Comment: Перегрузки метода `.GetDirectories()` смотрите, хотяб через IDE в которой пишете, сразуй поймете, что можно написать например так: `.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

Comment: Я написал в вопросе про  searchoption.alldirectories но он для меня не работает так как он выдает ошибку о правах доступа, а мне нужно игнорировать это просто пропустить данную папку и продолжить поиск по папкам где есть доступ

Comment: Ну тогда [рекурсивно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628606/220553) проходитесь и получайте то, что надо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно рекурсивно проходить каталоги.

```
void Main()
{
    string rootDir = @"x:\temp";
    Directories.GetDirs(rootDir);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> paths in  Directories.directoryPaths)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Root: {paths.Key}") // корневой
        foreach (var nestedDirs in paths.Value) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Child:{nestedDirs}"); // дочерние каталоги
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

class Directories
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string[]> directoryPaths = new();
    public static void GetDirs(string rootDir)
    {
        var nestedDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDir);
        directoryPaths[rootDir] = nestedDirs;
        foreach (var currentDir in nestedDirs);
        {
            GetDirs(currentDir); // вход в рекурсию
        }
    }
}
```