# Ошибки доступа к файлам при их поиске

Tags: c#, файлы

Мне нужно найти и получить путь к папке имея её название. При поиске выскакивают ошибки доступа к разным файлам по типу системных. Как мне скипать подобные файлы?

```
string Path = @"C:\";
IEnumerable<string> AllFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Path, "maFiles", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string Folder in AllFolders)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Folder);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628606/220553

Comment: Используйте [перегрузку](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-enumeratedirectories(system-string-system-string-system-io-enumerationoptions)), которая принимает параметр [EnumerationOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-6.0). Задайте  `IgnoreInaccessible = true`