# C# как получить список всех файлов в нужной директории, включая системные и защищенные

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом (методом) я могу получить список всех файлов (интересуют полные пути к ним) в указанной директории с датами изменения этих файлов. Необходимо, чтобы системные ограничения никак не помешали и итоговый список содержал бы исчерпывающий список файлов без единого пропуска. Те методы, которые я смог найти, пропускают системные и защищенные файлы.

P.S. Обдумываю идею программы, которая будет делать из стандартных приложений для Windows приложения типа Portable - для неё и нужно. Такие приложения уже есть, но они могут превратить в портативный далеко не любой софт. Предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что они пропускают какие-то важные для программ файлы в системе. Поэтому нужно получить исчерпывающий список. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не ко всем директориям у вас есть доступ, а значит и путь внутренних папок вы просто так не получите. А вообще, вопрос странный, ибо обычный `Directory.GetFiles("путь", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` выдаст вас все нужное, разве нет?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Directory.GetFiles выдает System.UnauthorizedAccessException - "отказано в доступе по пути..."

Comment: Ибо как я и сказал выше, вы не можете просто так получить то, к чему у вас нет доступа, ну а к системным папкам доступа у вас нет. Хотите избежать этой ошибки, используйте [рекурсивный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628606/220553) способ получения, где игнорируйте эту ошибку). Ну а если вы всеж хотите получить доступ к этой папке, то вам надо получить права у системы для учетной записи, а это, как по мне, весьма странное действие, да и наверно бесполезное для создания портативных приложений. И да "не любой софт" - ибо софт это не просто файлы, а еще и драйвера, реестр, и так далее.

Comment: Для реестра всё уже готово. Драйверами позже займусь, спасибо за подсказку) Пока нужно разобраться с доступом к файлам, это самая сложная и долгая часть. По поводу "и так далее" - если есть что-то ещё кроме драйверов, реестра и файлов, буде признателен, если подскажете. Меня, в принципе, устроит как крайний вариант перезагрузка в какую-нибудь Windows PE и захват из-под неё, если это сработает, но пока хочу перебрать все варианты получения доступа в самой винде - всё остальное будет как-то "неизящно"...))

Comment: "неизящно" лезть туда, куда не следует, доступ к папкам закрывают не просто так. Ну а если прям так хочется, то сначала попробуйте получить доступ к директории вручную (загуглите быстро как получить права), а потом сделайте тоже самое програмно. НО, не все директории так просто вам откроются, учитывайте этот факт. Кстати, по поводу портативок, есть PortableCreator, который вроде делает и так все, что вам нужно.

Comment: Я туда хочу слазить в порядке эксперимента, чтобы проверить, поможет ли это "опортотиветь" софт, который не получается сделать Portable с помощью существующих программ. Про PortableCreator знаю, он не со всем справляется, далеко. Кроме того, есть решение лучше - всё делается на символических ссылках. Но тоже не со всем справляется. Хочу взять за основу метод с символическими ссылками, прошерстить весь диск и проверить, поможет ли это - а там видно будет.